# How do I install wav2lip locally

Tags: python, flask, installation

I am making an API that requires installing wav2lip model, but when I try to install wav2lip model I get an error mentioned below.

**Error:**

```
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d5x90kao\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d5x90kao\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d5x90kao\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-d5x90kao\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a sub process, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

**Note:**
Below are path for python environment variables

C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
C:\Users\Moon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\

I am trying to install wav2lip model locally.
I am trying to find the solution to get rid of the error and successfully install wav2lip.

Comment: It says "No module named 'requests'". Try running pip install requests first and retry this installation after that is done.

Comment: I have already installed requests module but still getting the same error.